# Change Guideline percentage in constraint layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a guideline in constraint layout like this

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline8"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Later I want to change the `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent` value to something else conditionally. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

There is two ways to do it:

- Using [`ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.html#guidePercent)

> This method get a specific parameter from the `ConstraintLayout` and modify it.

```
Guideline guideLine = (Guideline) findViewById(R.id.your_guideline);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) guideLine.getLayoutParams();
params.guidePercent = 0.45f; // 45% // range: 0 <-> 1
guideLine.setLayoutParams(params);
```

- Using [`ConstraintSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html#setGuidelinePercent(int,%20float))

> This method consists in cloning the `ConstraintLayout` attributes, modifying them and then applying to the `View`.
>
> **BUT** it's very slow.

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_constraint_with_guideline);
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);        
constraintSet.setGuidelinePercent(R.id.your_guideline, 0.07f); // 7% // range: 0 <-> 1
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout);
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

---

### Creating a parallax effect

To test those methods I created a parallax animation using a `GuideLine` and a `ScrollView` on top.

On the `AndroidManifest.xml`, inside your `Activity`, add this: `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`.

```
     <activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
     ...
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
Guideline guideTopInfo;
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params;
ConstraintSet constraintSet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    guideTopInfo = (Guideline) findViewById(R.id.guideline2);
    constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraint_root);
    params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) guideTopInfo.getLayoutParams();

    //constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    //constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

    final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_front);
    scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            float percentage = scrollView.getScrollY() * 0.0001f; // 0.001f faster // 0.00001f slower parallax animation

            Log.d("mLog", String.valueOf(percentage));
            if(percentage >= 0) {
                // my XML percentage value was 12%
                params.guidePercent = 0.12f - percentage; // up
                //params.guidePercent = 0.12f + percentage; // downm
                guideTopInfo.setLayoutParams(params);

                //constraintSet.setGuidelinePercent(R.id.guideline2, 0.12f - percentage);
                //TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout);
                //constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

---

My other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928488/move-background-when-scrolling/44191875#44191875) about parallax if anyone is interested. ;)

Comment: I tried using Constraintset - nothing happend. Do you have any idea where i could start to search the Problem?

Comment: @kilianeller I suggest to use the ConstraitLayout.LayoutParams, due to Constraintset being too slow. Anyway, check for those things: 1- Did you set the id properly?  2-  When you change your guideline manually on the XML, the view change it axis?

Comment: Changing Guideline in XML works as expected. ConstraitLayout.LayoutParams also works as expected - i just wanted to use Constraintset for a easy Animation.

Answer (score 18):

```
guideline.setGuidelinePercent(value: Float)
```

This is enough to change the guideline percent during runtime.

Comment: Somehow, this doesn't seem to work for me during runtime

Answer (score 17):

This code will change you guidePercent to 0

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) guideline.getLayoutParams();
lp.guidePercent = 0;
guideline.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 10):

you cam make it center doing it worked with me i hope it helps

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ConstraintSet object to set layout_constraintGuide_percent in code.

Below is the code to set layout_constraintGuide_percent in code. First you need to create constraint set object, call clone method passing constraintlayout and then call setGuidelinePercent passing guideline id and ratio.

```
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

    constraintSet.setGuidelinePercent(R.id.guideline, 0.4f);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin & inside Fragment or other activities,set GuideLine app: related parameters has a little difficulty , but I Solved it in this way :

```
 val view = inflate(this, R.layout.ly_custom_menu_item_wallet_side_menu, null)
 val guideL = view.findViewById<Guideline>(R.id.guideline_wallet)
          var constParam: ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams = guideL.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
          constParam.guidePercent = 0.42f
          guideL.layoutParams = constParam
```

and this is Guideline element inside our   ly_custom_menu_item_wallet_side_menu.xml layout :

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/guideline_wallet"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
   app:layout_constraintGuide_end="84dp"  />
```